# Como ordenar o id de minha datatable de forma decrescente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Preciso listar todos os id de forma decrescente em minha datatable em jQuery.

Qual é o melhor caminho para isto?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.properties = <?= json_encode($ci_properties) ?>;
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#na_datatable').DataTable();
    $('body').on('click','.btn.view',function(e){
        var id = $(e.target).closest('.btn.view').data("id");
        var property = window.properties.find(p => p.propertie_id == id);
        $('#view-property .modal-body').html('');
        $('#view-property .modal-title .propertie-id').html(property.propertie_id);
        $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Bairro:</b> ${property.bairro}</div>`);
        $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Empreendimento:</b> ${property.empreendimento}</div>`);
        $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Apartamento:</b> ${property.apartamento}</div>`);
        $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Dormtirórios:</b> ${property.dormitorios}</div>`);
        $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Box:</b> ${property.box}</div>`);
        $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Mobiliado:</b> ${property.mobiliado}</div>`);
        $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Chaves:</b> ${property.chaves}</div>`);
        $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Proprietario:</b> ${property.proprietario}</div>`);
        $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Contato:</b> ${property.contato}</div>`);
        $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Valor:</b> ${property.valor}</div>`);
        $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Cadastro:</b> ${property.cadastro}</div>`);
        $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Atualizado:</b> ${property.atualizado}</div>`);
    });
} );
```

Atualmente está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas preciso listar sempre o último registro que foi cadastrado por primeiro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ordenar a primeira coluna em ordem decrescente, adicione a opção `order` na inicialização do componente:

```
$('#na_datatable').DataTable({
   "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
});
```

O `0` representa a primeira coluna.